# how distinguish whether a reference refers to an array or to a single value?

Tags: c#, arrays, wmi

I'm using WMI and it gives me a ManagementCollectionObject that include a collection of objects in different types such as string, int64, array of int, array of string and so on.

WMI Code Generator generates different code for single value and array values. as below:

```
// getting single value
Console.WriteLine("Availability: {0}", queryObj["Availability"]);


// getting single array value
if(queryObj["AvailableJobSheets"] == null)
   Console.WriteLine("AvailableJobSheets: {0}", queryObj["AvailableJobSheets"]);
else
{
    String[] arrAvailableJobSheets = (String[])(queryObj["AvailableJobSheets"]);
    foreach (String arrValue in arrAvailableJobSheets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AvailableJobSheets: {0}", arrValue);
    }
}
```

how can i distinguish whether the value of a property is array or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Type.IsArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isarray.aspx):

```
if(queryObj["AvailableJobSheets"].GetType().IsArray)
    // It's an array
```

Comment: after that, how can manipulate the different kind of array (string, int, char) with same code.

Comment: the object would contains a different kind of array. I want to get the values of array as string anyway and make it to a comma text value.

Comment: I think you should post a new question for this.